Modifying streaming text when reading and wrting csv file in Snowflake using Snowpark API
I have a text file in Snowfalake stage that I need to modify using a simple function and write to a different stage. The files are expected to be relatively small and at the moment my code reads text file into memory. What I am trying to work out is how to do the same using streaming so I only load one line at a time.
from utils.functions import create_snowpark_session


session = create_snowpark_session()


# reads csv from INTERNAL stage into memory
raw_file_lines = session.file.get_stream(interim_file_path).readlines() 

# returns reformatted csv as binary string
standard_file = standardize_file(raw_file_lines) 

# creates streaming object
bytes_io = BytesIO(bytes(standard_file)) 

# requirement to ouput file to write csv into EXTERNAL stage
session.file.put_stream(bytes_io, target_file_path, overwrite = True)

   # Function used to modify csv 
        def standardize_file(src_file_lines : list)-> b'str':
            # Removing double quotes from header names
            header = src_file_lines[0]
            header_new = [header.replace(b'"',b'')]

            # Removing double quotes around asterisk (*)
            records = src_file_lines[1:]
            records_new = []
            for rec in records:
                new_rec = rec.replace(b'"*"',b'*')
                records_new.append(new_rec)

            lines_new = header_new + records_new
            file_new = b''.join(lines_new)
            return file_new

